# Getting java.lang.RuntimeException in google play console Crashes and ANRs

Tags: react-native, google-play-console

I am getting this issue in google play console Crashes and ANRs I have tested the app on different devices it works perfectly I don't know what is the issue.

Application developed in React Native. How can I resolve this issue?

````
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3827)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4003)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2317)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8595)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: 
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:566)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate (FragmentContainer.java:57)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate (FragmentManager.java:390)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.<init> (FragmentStateManager.java:74)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.restoreSaveState (FragmentManager.java:2454)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.restoreSaveState (FragmentController.java:196)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:287)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate (AppCompatActivity.java:106)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onCreate (ReactActivity.java:44)
  at com.libonomywallet.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:21)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8207)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8191)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1309)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3800)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0 (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:343)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:548)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenFragment.<init> (ScreenFragment.kt:41)
  at com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStackFragment.<init> (ScreenStackFragment.kt:30)```
````

Comment: did you solved that?

Comment: I did not solve this.